# Ethical Hacking: Cracking my personal wireless network

Tags: kali-linux, wpa2, ethics, aircrack-ng

I am teaching myself ethical hacking.

Now, I am attempting to crack the password of my Verizon FIOS Router at home. Using Kali Linux 2 [based on this website](http://lewiscomputerhowto.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-hack-wpawpa2-wi-fi-with-kali.html).

Steps So Far

1. On Kali Linux typed airmon-ng and it listed my wireless adapter
2. Typed `airmon-ng start wlan0`
3. Typed `airodump-ng wlan0` and it listed my router's SSID twice with different BSSID.
4. Copied a BSSID and executed the command `airodump-ng c 6 --bssid [BSSID] -w /root/Desktop wlan0`

So far, I get this. I tried disconnecting and reconnecting to the network (both my smartphone and laptop), but it does not show client connecting. Let alone any 4-way handshake.

How to speed up the process so it shows client connecting? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Pretty much it depends on your Kali's WiFi signal strength. Try to use a wireless card with a strong antenna, or be closer to the router. From experience, you will capture the 4-way handshake if you were close enough

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question has been already answered [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57261/no-handshake-from-airodump), but I'll post mine as well.

From experience, it might be the following:

- You're not close enough to the router, there is a chance that you'll not capture the handshake if the client is too close to the AP and the monitor mode device is relatively far.
- A hardware issue, your network device is old and not compatible, so it can't capture packets from another protocols. For example if your device running 802.11g and the network is 802.11n

**Solution:** First, try to capture the handshake from different physical positions, if it doesn't work, try another WiFi device.

Answer (score -4):

## Ethical hacking

You can use Aircrack-ng or any tools you want and crack wireless network, but I suggest you learn how networking works and how TCP/IP and other protocols function. Here are some books about TCP/IP, ISO/OSI and HTTP/HTTPS:

- TCP/IP Architecture, Design and Implementation in Linux
- ISO/OSI Model
- HTTP: The Definitive Guide (Definitive Guides)
- HTTP Essentials: Protocols for Secure, Scaleable Web Sites

### Tool for wifi hacking

I think Aircrack is good, but not always. Sometimes it doesn't work on wifi secure. You can use `Wireshark`, `Fern WiFi Wireless Cracker` and `Wifite`.

#### Other

Before cracking a system, you should understand how it works. If you can't crack a wifi/password (now you're testing it on yourself, these tips can help you the next time) try phishing and fake login. It always works (When I was 14, I asked owner of wifi via email for his password. I said was a wifi technician, and he gave me it). If you could not crack it again, try: http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/hacking-tutorial/wifi-hacking-cracking-wpa2-password/#sthash.a30J8kEe.dpbs.

Comment: I agree, better to learn in depth. Me, I prefer to do hands-on exercise before reading (that's just me). I will research your links. Thank you.

Comment: Because you didn't even attempt to actually answer the question. Because you were rude. Because you did not assume good faith and instead assumed the poster is clueless.